# Cant able to create view with following snowflake query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Needs to create view with below columns. Need to understand how to create view using with clause inside the query.

```
create 
    or replace view TEST_RRX.DW_RRX.V_SIL_RRX_PTS_BusinessLocation_Dim(
      --ROW_WID,
      --ADDRESS_TYPE,
      BUSN_LOC_NAME, 
      BUSN_LOC_NUM, 
      BUSN_LOC_TYPE, 
      ST_ADDRESS1, 
      ST_ADDRESS2, 
      CITY_NAME, 
      POSTAL_CODE, 
      STATE_CODE, 
      COUNTRY_CODE, 
      ACTIVE_FLG, 
      CREATED_BY_WID, 
      CHANGED_BY_WID, 
      CREATED_ON_DT, 
      CHANGED_ON_DT, 
      AUX1_CHANGED_ON_DT, 
      AUX2_CHANGED_ON_DT, 
      AUX3_CHANGED_ON_DT, 
      AUX4_CHANGED_ON_DT, 
      SRC_EFF_FROM_DT, 
      SRC_EFF_TO_DT, 
      EFFECTIVE_FROM_DT, 
      EFFECTIVE_TO_DT, 
      DELETE_FLG, 
      CURRENT_FLG, 
      W_INSERT_DT, 
      W_UPDATE_DT, 
      DATASOURCE_NUM_ID, 
      --ETL_PROC_WID,
      INTEGRATION_ID, 
      --TENANT_ID,
      --X_CUSTOM,
      --GEO_COUNTRY_WID,
      --GEO_WID,
      UPD_FLG
    ) as WITH CODE AS (
      SELECT 
        W_CODE_D.MASTER_CODE AS MASTER_CODE, 
        W_CODE_D.MASTER_VALUE AS MASTER_VALUE, 
        W_CODE_D.SOURCE_CODE AS SOURCE_CODE, 
        W_CODE_D.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID AS DATASOURCE_NUM_ID, 
        W_CODE_D.SOURCE_CODE_1 as SOURCE_CODE_1, 
        W_CODE_D.SOURCE_CODE_2 as SOURCE_CODE_2, 
        W_CODE_D.SOURCE_NAME_1 as SOURCE_NAME_1, 
        W_CODE_D.CATEGORY 
      FROM 
        W_CODE_D 
      WHERE 
        W_CODE_D.LANGUAGE_CODE = 'E'
    ), 
    USER_TAB as (
      SELECT 
        LOOKUP_TABLE.ROW_WID as ROW_WID, 
        LOOKUP_TABLE.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID as DATASOURCE_NUM_ID, 
        LOOKUP_TABLE.INTEGRATION_ID as INTEGRATION_ID, 
        LOOKUP_TABLE.EFFECTIVE_FROM_DT as EFFECTIVE_FROM_DT, 
        LOOKUP_TABLE.EFFECTIVE_TO_DT as EFFECTIVE_TO_DT 
      FROM 
        DW_RRX.W_USER_D LOOKUP_TABLE
    ), 
    BUSN_LOCATION as (
      SELECT 
        sq.BUSN_LOC_NAME, 
        sq.BUSN_LOC_NUM, 
        sq.BUSN_LOC_TYPE, 
        sq.ST_ADDRESS1, 
        sq.ST_ADDRESS2, 
        case when CITY.MASTER_VALUE is null then (
          case when sq.CITY_NAME is null 
          OR LENGTH(sq.CITY_NAME) = 0 
          OR REGEXP_INSTR(sq.CITY_NAME, ' ')> 0 then 'Unspecified' else sq.CITY_NAME end
        ) else CITY.MASTER_VALUE end as city_name, 
        sq.POSTAL_CODE, 
        case when STATE.MASTER_CODE is null then (
          case when sq.STATE_CODE is null 
          OR LENGTH(sq.STATE_CODE) = 0 
          OR REGEXP_INSTR(sq.STATE_CODE, ' ')> 0 then 'Unspecified' else sq.STATE_CODE end
        ) else STATE.MASTER_CODE end as STATE_CODE, 
        case when COUNTRY.MASTER_CODE is null then (
          case when sq.COUNTRY_CODE is null 
          OR LENGTH(sq.COUNTRY_CODE) = 0 
          OR REGEXP_INSTR(sq.COUNTRY_CODE, ' ')> 0 then 'Unspecified' else sq.COUNTRY_CODE end
        ) else COUNTRY.MASTER_VALUE end as COUNTRY_CODE, 
        'Y' as ACTIVE_FLG, 
        CREATED_BY.ROW_WID AS CREATED_BY_WID, 
        CHANGED_BY.ROW_WID AS CREATED_BY_WID, 
        sq.AUX1_CHANGED_ON_DT, 
        sq.AUX2_CHANGED_ON_DT, 
        sq.AUX3_CHANGED_ON_DT, 
        sq.AUX4_CHANGED_ON_DT, 
        sq.SRC_EFF_FROM_DT, 
        sq.SRC_EFF_TO_DT, 
        case when W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.INTEGRATION_ID is null then current_date else W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.W_INSERT_DT end as EFFECTIVE_FROM_DT, 
        TO_DATE('01013714', 'DDMMYYYY') as EFFECTIVE_TO_DT, 
        'N' As DELETE_FLG, 
        'Y' AS CURRENT_FLG, 
        case when W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.INTEGRATION_ID is null then current_date else W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.W_INSERT_DT end as W_INSERT_DT, 
        W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.W_UPDATE_DT as current_date, 
        sq.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID, 
        --sq.ETL_PROC_WID, 
        sq.INTEGRATION_ID, 
        CASE WHEN (
          SELECT 
            ETL_PROC_WID 
          FROM 
            TEST_RRX.DW_RRX.W_PARAM_G 
          WHERE 
            ROW_WID = 1
        ) = W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.ETL_PROC_WID THEN 'X' WHEN W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.INTEGRATION_ID IS NULL THEN 'I' WHEN W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.INTEGRATION_ID IS NOT NULL 
        AND (
          sq.CHANGED_ON_DT <> W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.CHANGED_ON_DT 
          OR sq.AUX1_CHANGED_ON_DT <> W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.AUX1_CHANGED_ON_DT 
          OR sq.AUX2_CHANGED_ON_DT <> W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.AUX2_CHANGED_ON_DT 
          OR sq.AUX3_CHANGED_ON_DT <> W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.AUX3_CHANGED_ON_DT 
          OR sq.AUX4_CHANGED_ON_DT <> W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.AUX4_CHANGED_ON_DT
        ) THEN 'U' END as UPD_FLG 
      FROM 
        DW_RRX.W_BUSN_LOCATION_DS sq 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CODE COUNTRY ON COUNTRY.SOURCE_CODE = sq.country_code 
        AND COUNTRY.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID = sq.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID 
        AND COUNTRY.CATEGORY = 'COUNTRY' 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CODE CITY ON CITY.SOURCE_CODE_1 = sq.country_code 
        AND CITY.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID = sq.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID 
        AND CITY.SOURCE_CODE_2 = sq.STATE_CODE 
        AND CITY.SOURCE_NAME_1 = sq.CITY_NAME 
        AND CITY.CATEGORY = 'CITY' 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CODE STATE ON STATE.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID = sq.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID 
        AND STATE.CATEGORY = 'STATE' 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN USER_TAB CREATED_BY ON sq.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID = CREATED_BY.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID 
        AND CREATED_BY.INTEGRATION_ID = sq.CREATED_BY_ID 
        and CREATED_BY.EFFECTIVE_FROM_DT <= sq.CREATED_ON_DT 
        and CREATED_BY.EFFECTIVE_TO_DT >= sq.CREATED_ON_DT 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN USER_TAB CHANGED_BY ON sq.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID = CHANGED_BY.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID 
        AND CHANGED_BY.INTEGRATION_ID = sq.CHANGED_BY_ID 
        and CHANGED_BY.EFFECTIVE_FROM_DT <= sq.CHANGED_ON_DT 
        and CHANGED_BY.EFFECTIVE_TO_DT >= sq.CHANGED_ON_DT 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN W_BUSN_LOCATION_D ON sq.INTEGRATION_ID = W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.INTEGRATION_ID 
        AND sq.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID = W_BUSN_LOCATION_D.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID
    ) 
    SELECT 
      * 
    FROM 
      BUSN_LOCATION 
    WHERE 
      UPD_FLG <> 'X'
```

Getting SQL compilation error: Invalid column definition list
Needs to create view with above columns

Comment: You need to list the individual columns in the correct order in your final SQL statement, rather than use SELECT *

Comment: Count the number of columns you define at the top of the statement and then count the number of columns in your `BUSN_LOCATION` CTE/WITH. Do they match? I count 29 columns defined at the top and only 27 columns coming through your `SELECT *`. The issue isn't your CTEs, rather your mismatch of column/schema definition and selected columns to fill the schema. It's just a good rule in SQL to avoid `SELECT *`, especially in view definitions.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same problem.
The solution is quite easy.

**Problem**: This error happens when there is a mismatch between the columns you get from the subquery and the column list you define just under the create view statement.

**Solution**:Either remove the column list under the create view statement or correct the number or order of the columns you have defined.